# Issue creating a SSAS Dimension that takes a general ledger period and maps it to a date value

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, date, ssas

**Requirement**

We would like to create a “Smart Period” dimension within SSAS that takes a general ledger period and maps it to a date value, so that we can use the date analysis functionality when querying our data, by period, within Excel.

The following articles discuss how to create a custom (& fiscal) calendars from data sets that don’t contain records with simple date timestamps that are natural dates.

```
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Analysis+Services+(SSAS)/71140/
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f1a94192-6eb1-4633-a56c-3c90c826584f/ssas-ytd-issue-fiscal-vs-calendar?forum=sqlanalysisservices
http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2014/creating-financial-year-dimension-using-ssa
```

**Data to support the new dimension**

The challenge is that our transactions are stamped with the General Ledger Period (e.g. 201600 to 201614) - so there’s more than 12 periods in a financial year. We also want to provide a Calendar view (Jan to Dec) and a Fiscal view (Apr-Mar) on the same data set. The user want to have GL periods 201612 and 201613 reportable but typically presented in one Fiscal period 201612.

Our base database table is called tbl.SmartPeriod, I have included SQL to create this table at the end of this question, and it is set up as follows:

[image: Screenshot of the Smart Period table's contents]

*SmartDataKey* - The values held in this column show the General Ledger (GL) periods within our organisation, Periods 201500, 201513 & 201514 are included for accountancy purposes.

*FullServiceDateAlternativeKey* – This date value corresponds to a month in the financial year that we want to map the GL period to.

*AriesStylePeriod* – The Enterprise Resource Planner system (ERP) within our organisation, which is called ARIES, hides the GL periods that are used for accountancy purposes from users. By mapping the GL periods to the Fiscal periods held in the ERP, that the general user population see when viewing transaction data on the ERP, we will allow analysis on SSAS that matches their view of our data.

**SSAS Dimension**

We have mapped this data into a Dimension called *Smart Period* within SSAS, the following screenshots provide a high level overview of its configuration.

[image: Smart Period Dimension Structure]

[image: Smart Period Attribute Relationships]

[image: Smart Period - Data Browser Output]

**Issue**

We would like to filter the ARIES period value using the date filters within Excel, our work so far has resulted in getting the filters work successfully when looking at Months or Quarters. However, when applying the Year filter in Excel we get the values from a Calendar Year in the Smart Period table (e.g. Quarter 4 from the previous Fiscal year and the first three Quarters of this Fiscal year, rather than the four quarters from the current Financial Year).

We cannot release this functionality until we can get the “Year Filter” in Excel to map to the Fiscal Year so that the three date filters that we require (e.g. Month, Quarter & Year) are all working correctly. At present we can only get the Month and Quarter filters to map to the correct Period values.

We would be willing to drop the calendar year requirement and delete any reference to it from the Smart Period Dimension if this would help with a solution, as this functionality is only required by a small subset of the users.

**SQL to generate the Smart Period Data Table**

```
 /*
    This SQL generates a table that will hold the GL and Fiscal periods 
    in a hierarchy that support the operation of a Smart Period dimension in SSAS
*/

/* Create the Smart Period Table

--USE [CubeCreationSupport]
--GO

--/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblSmartPeriod]    Script Date: 04/11/2016 12:05:23 ******/
--SET ANSI_NULLS ON
--GO

--SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
--GO

--CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSmartPeriod](
--  [SmartDateKey] [int] NOT NULL,
--  [FullSmartDateAlternateKey] [date] NOT NULL,
--  [ARIESStylePeriod] [int] NOT NULL,
--  [MonthName] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
--  [MonthNumberOfYear] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
--  [CalendarQuarter] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
--  [CalendarYear] [smallint] NOT NULL,
--  [FiscalPeriod] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
--  [FiscalQuarter] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
--  [FiscalYear] [smallint] NOT NULL,
--  [FiscalSemester] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
-- CONSTRAINT [PK_DimDate_SmartDateKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
--(
--  [SmartDateKey] ASC
--)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
-- CONSTRAINT [AK_DimDate_FullSmartDateAlternateKey] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
--(
--  [FullSmartDateAlternateKey] ASC
--)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
--) ON [PRIMARY]

--GO

--*/


DECLARE @ct INT
DECLARE @InputDate DATETIME
DECLARE @FinYear INT
DECLARE @CalYear INT
DECLARE @FYPeriods TABLE (SmartDateKey INT, FullSmartDateAlternateKey DATE,  ARIESStylePeriod INT, EnglishMonthName Varchar(20), MonthNumberOfYear INT, CalendarQuarter INT , CalendarYear INT, FiscalPeriod INT, FiscalQuarter INT, FiscalYear INT, FiscalSemester INT)    -- Choose INT or VARCHAR(6), no need to modify code


DECLARE @YearCount INT


SET     @InputDate = '1971-04-01'

SET     @FinYear = (SELECT
                        CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,@InputDate) > 3 THEN DATEPART(YEAR, @InputDate)
                        ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, @InputDate) - 1
                        END)
SET     @CalYear = DATEPART(YEAR, @InputDate) -- - 1

SET @YearCount = 0;

WHILE @YearCount < 81

BEGIN

            SET @ct = 0;

            WHILE @ct < 1

            BEGIN

                INSERT @FYPeriods
                SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear) + '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct) -- DateKey
                ,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear)+'-04-01') -- FullDateAlternateKey 
                ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@CalYear) + '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct+1) -- ARIESStyle Period 
                ,LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear)+'-04-01')),3) -- MonthName
                ,4 -- MonthNumberOfYear
                ,2 -- CalendarQuarter
                ,@CalYear -- CalendarYear
                ,1 -- FiscalPeriod
                ,1 -- FiscalQuarter
                ,@FinYear -- FiscalYear
                ,1 -- FiscalSemester

                SET @ct = @ct + 1;

            END;

            WHILE @ct < 10

            BEGIN

                INSERT @FYPeriods
                SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear) + '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct) 
            --  ,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct+3)+'-02')
                ,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@CalYear)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct+3)+'-02')
                ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear) + '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct)
                ,LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct+3)+'-02')),3)
                ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct+3)
                ,CASE   
                      WHEN (@ct/3.0) <= 1.0 THEN 2   
                      WHEN (@ct/3.0) <= 2.0 THEN 3
                      ELSE 4   
                 END  
                 ,@CalYear
                 ,@ct
                 ,CASE   
                      WHEN @ct < 4 THEN 1   
                      WHEN @ct < 7 THEN 2
                      ELSE 3   
                 END  
                 ,@FinYear 
                 ,1

               SET @ct = @ct + 1;

            END;

            -- @ct = 10

            WHILE @ct <= 12

            BEGIN

                INSERT @FYPeriods
                SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@ct) 
                -- ,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear+1)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct-9)+'-02') 
                ,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@CalYear+1)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct-9)+'-02') 
                ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct)
                ,LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct-9)+'-02')) ,3)
                ,@ct-9
                ,1
                ,@CalYear+1 -- @FinYear + 1
                ,@ct
                ,4
                ,@FinYear 
                ,2

               SET @ct = @ct + 1;

            END;

            WHILE @ct <= 14

            BEGIN

                INSERT @FYPeriods
                SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@ct)  
                -- ,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear+1)+'-03-0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct-10)) 
                ,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@CalYear+1)+'-03-0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct-10)) 
                ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,12)
                ,LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FinYear)+'-03-0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ct-10))),3) 
                ,3
                ,1
                ,@CalYear+1 -- @FinYear+1 
                ,12
                ,4
                ,@FinYear 
                ,2

               SET @ct = @ct + 1;

            END;

        SET @FinYear = @FinYear +1;
        SET @CalYear = @CalYear +1;
        SET @YearCount = @YearCount +1;     

END;

--Select * From @FYPeriods


Delete FROM dbo.tblSmartPeriod


INSERT INTO dbo.tblSmartPeriod ([SmartDateKey],[FullSmartDateAlternateKey],[ARIESStylePeriod],[MonthName],[MonthNumberOfYear],[CalendarQuarter],[CalendarYear],[FiscalPeriod],[FiscalQuarter],[FiscalYear],[FiscalSemester]) 
SELECT [SmartDateKey],[FullSmartDateAlternateKey],[ARIESStylePeriod],[EnglishMonthName],[MonthNumberOfYear],[CalendarQuarter],[CalendarYear],[FiscalPeriod],[FiscalQuarter],[FiscalYear],[FiscalSemester] FROM @FYPeriods



Select * From dbo.tblSmartPeriod
```